# Facebook not showing open graph preview (static html5 on amazon s3)

Tags: html, facebook, amazon-s3, facebook-opengraph

I want to share this link (https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/lavorotrentino/index.html) through a Facebook status.

The problem I'm facing is the missing facebook preview that should be based on the meta tag info in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="it">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/lavorotrentino/index.html" />
<link rel="image_src" href="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/lavorotrentino/abc.jpg"/>
<title>Lavoro in Trentino</title>

<meta property="og:title" content="Lavoro in Trentino" />
<meta property='og:site_name' content='LIT' /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Nuove opportunità pubblicate oggi sul portale dell'Agenzia del Lavoro trentina."/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/lavorotrentino/index.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/lavorotrentino/abc.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/lavorotrentino/abc.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />   

</head>
```

I tried to find the problem with the Open Graph Object Debugger but it seems like the tags are ok:

Facebook Object Debugger result:
[image].

**The message warning**:

> "*fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( 966242223397117 ) will be assigned.*"

**should not be a problem for simply sharing a link.**

Are there issues with the amazon s3 free 1 year trial?

Comment: You'll definitely gonna need a app_id. This is easy, and can be done in a few minutes. But, if you want to publish as a "story", including articles, you'll need the app to be published, which requires a lot more effort. Facebook API is like that, as more complicated for us seems to be better for them.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to post using open-graph you do need an appID. It was easy to make.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started#create-app

Comment: Actually it seems that _fb:app_id_ is needed when you want an **Open Graph Story**. For a simple link post there's no need of it in order to get the preview. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @steber did you try making the App Id? I could not get it to work without it, even for something simple like an article.

Check this out for reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article/

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. Actually I tried also to move the website/article from amazon s3 to a free web hosting service http://www.biz.nf. Here there's no problem. I can share my link on facebook and get the preview. I don't know what I'm missing on s3, it's such an easy task